# Azure kubernetes - Azure Service endpoint configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-aks

I am trying to avoid exposing the backend Azure Sql database over the Internet and I understood that Azure service endpoint is the way to achieve this.

Is there any documentation or example available for Azure kubernetes that uses Service endpoint to connect to the Azure Sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you go through this [`documentation`](https://azure.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-sql-database-now-generally-available/) You just need to create the firewall rule using VNET service endpoints.

Step by step guidance is given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview#azure-portal-steps).

Comment: I did go through the documentation however couldn't understand how the Azure Sql public ip (eg: 13.10.10.5 that points to mydb.azure.net) will be converted into a private ip (eg: 10.5.5.5 would refer to mydb.azure.net)? Would the connection string get changed, which I have to update in my appsettings?

Comment: There is a good reference here - https://blog.coeo.com/azure-service-endpoints - on how it works.